# Get value from unchecked checkbox in play

Tags: java, html, forms, checkbox, playframework

I need to get the value for an unchecked checkbox using the Play framework. I can get the value if I check the checkbox.

My html is as follows

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="correctAnswer" value="true">
```

This is how I get the data in the controller, which gives me an array of only checked boxes

```
  String[] segaMega = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("correctAnswer");
```

I have tried doing the hidden field before the checkbox trick, but that didnt work very well. Does play have anything that can help me?

Comment: This is not a Play Framework problem but a HTML design. By default, the form doesn't submit the values of unchecked checkboxes. If you would want to pass *all* the values from the checkboxes (even the unchecked) you should add a new parameter to the request, you can do it using a hidden field (as you already tried out) **or** using JavaScript/jQuery in order to get all the values from the checkboxes and pass them as a new parameter. This still is a bad idea, what's your real functional requirement?

Comment: Ok, that's a high level definition of your requirement. Looks like you need to handle the values of the checkbox in a hidden field or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you really need to have both the checked values and the full list of values on server side. The best bet would have a hidden field in the form which will hold the values of your checkboxes concatenated by a separator. In this example, I'll use a pipe (`|`).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function beforeSubmitQuestion() {
        var hidden = document.getElementById("hidChxValues");
        hidden.value = "";
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("correctAnswer");
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            hidden.value += checkboxes[i].value + "|";
        }
        return false;
    };
</script>

<form id="yourForm" onsubmit="beforeSubmitQuestion(); ">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidChxValues" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="correctAnswer" value="true" /> Valid
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="correctAnswer" value="false" /> Invalid
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I've made a test in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdDbg/ with the exception that I use a `type="text"` instead of `type="hidden"` in order to see the concatenated values and added `return false;` at the end of `onsubmit` to avoid form submission to the server (that will return in an error).

The server side code can be handled using Play or another technology, even plain Servlets.